# How to give default alternatives in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

After going through the docs twice, I gave up and wrote this in a template:

```
{{#if myVar}}{{myVar}}{{else}}{{myDefaultVar}}{{/if}}
```

Am I missing some Handlebars built-in feature for this, as it feels like it is going to come up a lot! (I realize I can write my own helper for it, and will do that if Handlebars has nothing built-in.)

Comment: what's the value of myVar ???

Comment: @MaheshSapkal I want myDefaultVar shown when myVar is false/blank/undefined/etc. When myVar has content I want myVar shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pending some discovery that Handlebars supports this natively, here is the helper I wrote:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("P", function(){
  for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;++i)if(arguments[i])return arguments[i];
});
```

So the long `{{#if}}` becomes this:

```
{{P myVar myDefaultVar}}
```

It allows multiple defaults, using whichever comes first, so I might have something like this:

```
Welcome {{P user.nickname user.fullName "guest"}}!
```

If the user has given a nickname, use that, otherwise use their full name. If they have given neither, refer to them as "guest".